# Java 10, Intellij Warning (class is not exported, accessing in same module)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-10, java-module

I am trying to use Java 10 with intellij in one of my project and came across a warning.

[image]

It is saying that I am not exporting class Server. If you see my package structure, I have Server inside `network` package my module-info file looks like this

```
module core {
    requires com.google.guice;

    requires io.netty.all;

    requires config;

    requires org.apache.logging.log4j;

    exports com.money.heist.server.core;

    opens com.money.heist.server.core.network to com.google.guice;
}
```

I am intentionally not exporting the package network as I don't want to do that but I want to use classes inside network package inside the parent package.

Is their any good/bad practice here or it is just intelliJ going crazy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you would expand the warning message, you would find the reason behind it

> In addition to that, in Java 9 a module may hide some of its classes
>   by not exporting their packages.
>
> If the public API of a class in an exported package references a class
>   from a non-exported package, such API isn't useful outside of the
>   module.

The reason such API isn't useful is that no other module can instantiate/access `Server` class.

Noticeably, in your module descriptor, you've included

```
opens com.money.heist.server.core.network to com.google.guice;
```

which would provide access *at run time, but not compile time*(possibly the reason why IntelliJ doesn't sense it), to the `public` and `protected` types in the package, and the `public` and `protected` members of those types to the modules they are opened to.

To relate to the above, if you change the `opens` directive to `exports`, you wouldn't further see the warning from IntelliJ.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks a lot!